Replace image with different aspect ratio within component and adjusting auto layout accordingly?
I’ve got a component with two elements inside: an image (top) and a text box (bottom). The component uses auto layout (vertical layout). I need to be able to replace the image within a component instance and have the auto layout adjust accordingly if the new image is a different size than the original. So if the image I’m adding has a smaller height than the original, the text box move up accordingly. The image should always fill the space horizontally. Is this possible?
A quick visual aid:
Taller Image:                 Shorter Image:
┌──────────────────────────┐  ┌──────────────────────────┐
│ ┌──────────────────────┐ │  │ ┌──────────────────────┐ │
│ │ Image                │ │  │ │ Image                │ │
│ │                      │ │  │ │                      │ │
│ │                      │ │  │ │                      │ │
│ │                      │ │  │ └──────────────────────┘ │
│ │                      │ │  │ ┌──────────────────────┐ │
│ │                      │ │  │ │ Text box             │ │
│ │                      │ │  │ └──────────────────────┘ │
│ └──────────────────────┘ │  └──────────────────────────┘
│ ┌──────────────────────┐ │
│ │ Text box             │ │
│ └──────────────────────┘ │
└──────────────────────────┘

